# Simplifying multiple equality checks in C

Tags: c

In c, to search for the letters a-z, I can do the following loop:

```
char s[10];
int c;
int has_letter = 0;

for (int i=0; (c=s[i])!='\0'; i++) {
    if (c>='a' && c<='z')
        has_letter = 1;
}
```

However, what the are chars are not contiguous, for example:

```
// see if any of the following letters are in it: 'adiuo'
char s[10];
int c;
int has_letter = 0;

for (int i=0; (c=s[i])!='\0'; i++) {
    if (c=='a' || c=='d' || c=='i' || c=='u' || c=='o')
        has_letter = 1;
}
```

Is there a way to simplify that construction? For example, doing something like:

```
char s[10];
int c;
int has_letter = 0;

for (int i=0; (c=s[i])!='\0'; i++) {
    if (c in "adiuo") // possible to do something like this?
        has_letter = 1;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted fails to initialize `has_letter` before entering the loop, so there's no telling what value it will have unless the loop assigns `1` to it.

Comment: You've couched the question in terms of testing individual characters one at a time, but for what your example code accomplishes, you don't need much more than a single call to `strcspn()` to test *all* the characters of `s` in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for this there is a helper function from `string.h`:

```
if (strchr("adiuo", c) != NULL)
```

The `strchr()` function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character in the string or `NULL` if the character is not found. So just check if it returns not `NULL`, which means a character was found in the string.

Answer (score 4):

`strpbrk()` does exactly what I think you want to do. You use it like

```
const char mask[] = "adiuo";

if ( strpbrk( str, mask ) ) {
  //do whatever...
}
```

The function returns a pointer to the first character in `str` that appears in the string `mask`. If it's non null, it's there.

Answer (score -1):

```
char s[10];
int c, has_letter;

const char* letters = "adiuo";

has_letter = 0;
for (int i=0; (c=s[i])!='\0'; i++) {
    if (strchr(letters, c) != NULL) {
        has_letter = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I just fixed it.